# JavaFx button event handler,cannot be resolved as a variable

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, handle

**In the handle method it says executeButton cannot be resolved in the handle method. Why is that? I am new to javafx. I did everything as the tutorial on youtube promped me.. This is not a complete code here, just an approximation**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class BankApplication extends Application implements 
EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Button executeButton = new Button("Execute");
    executeButton.setOnAction(this);        

}

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == executeButton) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Basic variable scope 101: Local variables are not visible outside of the method where they are declared. You need to change `executeButton` to a field if you want to access it from the `handle` method. Or you simply use different `EventHandler`s for triggering different effects and don't need to check the source.

Answer (score 0):

Make button into an instance variable so that it can be accessed from event handler.

```
public class BankApplication extends Application implements
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
private Button executeButton = new Button("Execute");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    executeButton.setOnAction(this);

}

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == executeButton) {

    }
}
}
```